# what is the difference between various sound sources in android system?

Tags: android, audio, audiorecord, audiotrack

I am trying to build a real time noise reduction program in Android
I use AudioRecord to obtain raw input sound data and AudioTrack to play it back.
While initializing Audiorecord, I use the code

```
record = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION, SAMPLE_FREQUENCY, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, min);
```

and when playing it back I use the code

```
track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION, SAMPLE_FREQUENCY, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, maxJitter, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
```

These settings work great for my Nexus 7 tablet (NOT phone), but when I tried to run it an LG Optimus (or any other mobile phone), the output volume is very low, even at hardware's maximum. If I change AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION to some other values, sometimes there is no output at all, or sometimes there is loud output when the program is executed the first time, then no output in the subsequent runs. This problem is not seen in the Nexus 7 (while some options do cause no sound output in the Nexus 7 as well)

(I perform FFT on the raw audio data, then run it through a noise reduction algorithm function to calculate gain values for each frequency component after FFT, and multiply the final output with thsi gain value. I have been able to figure out that whenever there is no output from the speakers, it is usually due to these gain values getting a value of NaN, but that is a different problem).

What I want to know is, what exactly is the difference between the various types of audio output sources defined in `Audiomanager`, such as `AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION` and the audio input sources in `MediaRecorder.AudioSource` ? Why do some of their options cause different behavior in tablet and phone?

--- EDIT ---
Also I was recently told that, in the phone, after this program is executed, the output in the phone sounds small, and after exiting the program, the sound in the normal operation of the phone continues to stay at that small volume. How do I make sure that all the sound related (or any other of the phone's resources) go back to their original settings once the program is terminated ?

--- EDIT 2 ---
Old initialization code:

```
int min = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_FREQUENCY, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
record = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION, SAMPLE_FREQUENCY, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, min);
int maxJitter = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_FREQUENCY, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, SAMPLE_FREQUENCY, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, maxJitter, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
am = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION); // ORIGINAL   AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION
```

--- EDIT 3 ---
Current initialization scheme

```
am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION); // ADDED LATER: DELETE THIS LINE IF IT CAUSES PROBLEMS
int min = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_FREQUENCY, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
record = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION, SAMPLE_FREQUENCY, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, min);
int maxJitter = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_FREQUENCY, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, SAMPLE_FREQUENCY, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, maxJitter, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
```

--- EDIT 4 ---
Code in onResume()

```
am = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
currentAudioManagerMode = am.getMode();  
... // (function with initialization code from EDIT 3)
```

Code in onPause()

```
am.setMode(currentAudioManagerMode);
```

Comment: The first argument to the `AudioTrack` constructor is a stream type, not an audio mode. You just happened to be lucky that MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION has the same value as STREAM_MUSIC.

Comment: yeah I realized that, I have changed it in my code, but I still don't get why the program behaves differently in a tablet and a phone

Comment: Are you using `setMode` anywhere in your app? Also, what type of recording are you making? Are you recording sound that's close to the phone (e.g. a dictaphone) or sounds that are far (like a couple of meters) away?

Comment: Please see my update. Previously I used to initialize as shown above. But apparently this problem was not seen at that time (or may be it was, but they just didn't notice) so I deleted the `setMode()` part. Someone else is testing this on a phone and I am posting here based on their feedback. Currently I initialize as shown in edit 3.

Comment: Alright. Since you're changing the audio mode to MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION, it's quite likely that the output will be routed to the earpiece instead of the loudspeaker on the phone. If you really need to use that audio mode you could try using `setSpeakerPhoneOn(true)`.

Comment: for my application I need to sound to be routed to the earpiece. Upto now this has been happening automatically after I insert the headphone jack, so never paid much attention to that. But after my program closes, I want all sound related settings to comeback to whatever it was before.

Comment: _"I need to sound to be routed to the earpiece. Upto now this has been happening automatically after I insert the headphone jack"_. Huh? By earpiece I mean the small speaker located at the top front of the phone, which is used primarily for voice calls. If you attached headphones the audio should be routed to the hedphones by default.

Comment: Non the less, currently I have also added the code as shown in EDIT 4 above. Should this be enough to bring the phone back to whatever state it was before my program (at least in terms of audio) ?

Comment: oh I'm sorry I think I added my comment while you were sending yours I think. Anyway, I need my program's output to come from the headphone (my development tablet does not have an earpiece so I got confused when you mentioned it, sorry about that)

Answer (score 1):

If you need more information that what's given in the [SDK API documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html), then may i suggest you refer the respective [source code](http://androidxref.com/source/xref/frameworks/base/media/java/android/media/AudioManager.java)? Likewise, you can do the same for MediaRecorder class.

WRT to your issue that the audio settings are changed after you run your app, i would suggest you first read the modes when you start your app (using respective `getMode()` methods on the hardware resource) and save them and restore the same when you exit/go-into-background your app (using respective `setMode()` methods on the hardware resource). The hardware resource here are MediaRecorder and AudioManager.

HTH.

Comment: sorry but looking at the source code isn't giving any idea on what exactly, for example, `AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION` is. The source code just shows that MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION is a `public static int` which is all that is given in the android developers website as well. Is there any other source that has more details regarding low level audio tasks in android?

Comment: Also, I can find a getMode() function for the AudioManager (audio output) but I cannot find an equivalent getMode() for the AudioSource(input). Only thing I found was `getAudioSourceMax()` inside the `MediaRecorder` class, and it also seems to always return a constant value of 6 (Source code:   http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2.2_r1/android/media/MediaRecorder.java#MediaRecorder.getAudioSourceMax%28%29   )

Comment: @user13267 Have you tried looking at the kernel source code? I would suggest you download the source code from google - http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html. The other possible modules could be under "hardware" or "frameworks" folder.

Comment: `This document describes how to download the source tree for a specific Android code-line.` Does this mean I can download code for a particular class only? And what will be different between this downloaded code and the source code shown in the webpage you linked in your answer? Also, it looks like the downlaod instructions are for a linux computer and I only have windows XP

Comment: I believe the "master" branch contains all the API-level code-lines. If you need a specific API-level, you use the "repo init" command with a "-b" option. More info on what google means by code-line is given here: http://source.android.com/source/code-lines.html. You can install cygwin on Windows XP and checkout the source code. Before you do that, you have to first do this setup: http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html. There might be easier way on Windows XP that i might not know. The advantage of checking out code-line vs the website (grepcode, etc) is that kernel src is present.

Comment: Having said all these things, i think you should not be digging so deep when you are working on application level. For audio in particular, i have seen folks going the NDK way (use JNI and OpenSLES) for finer access to audio hardware resources. There are sample apps in the samples folder of the Android NDK if you want to check out that route. HTH.

Comment: all this looks too complicated to be done right now (may be something to do n weekend?), and I am not sure what `kernel src` is like or if I'll be able to understand it if I see it. Is it like C code? Is any sample available anywhere so that I can check it out and see if it's worth downloading all this?

Comment: I don't have much experience with NDK and since I am still a relative beginner in Java and Android, I am afraid starting NDK might be like starting to learn another programming language (which I cannot give much time to right now). I was really hoping to find some more user friendly explanation of AudioManager, AudioRecord, etc. and the different types of audio modes and audio sources than what is available in the developers website

Comment: I've seen that most android books do not address these issues properly either, whenever it comes to audio they just explain surfacially about MediaRecorder and MediaPlayer for audio and leave it at that

Comment: I agree with your assessment and share the frustration as well. Unfortunately, from the application level, we don't have much control or much information except what's given on the SDK site. To answer your `kernel src`, i believe it's C/C++ since i see they are using gcc for building. I guess if u just need the kernel, u can get it from here: http://source.android.com/source/building-kernels.html. Sorry. Can't be of any more help, i guess.

Comment: NDK is just a marriage of C/C++ with Java using JNI as the bond. It's archaic and documentation is hard to find - authentic source is Oracle Website. May be you can check some audio related open source apps to see how they use these parameters. For ex, the phone app or music app might be useful to look at since those control/manipulate volume based on various states. Also, apps that route audio to bluetooth, etc might help gain some insight as well. Anyways, good luck.